# I have to press submit button twice in IE using jquery framework to submit form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a strange behaviour in IE browser.

I have simple form:

```
<form name="test" id="test" action="some_url_here" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="url" id="url" class="required" />
  <input type="text" name="page" id="page" class="required" />
  ...
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

and in JS:

```
var result = true; 

$("#test").on("submit", function(){
   $(".required").removeClass("error");
   $.each($("input.required"), function(k, v) {
      if($(this).val() === '') {
         $(this).addClass("error");
         result = false;
         return false;
      }
   });

  if(result) {
    if(!IsValidUrl($("input[name='url']").val()){
       $("input[name='url']").addClass("error");
       return false;
    }
  } else {
    return false;
  }
});
```

Let's assume that I filled all fields correctly.

In Chrome & Firefox, when I press on submit button then works fine, just once time.

In IE (all versions) I have to press two times on the submit form to execute/sumbit the form.

Why ?

I tried also to put after `IsValidUrl` condition:

```
$(this).submit();
```

But no success.

Comment: Isn't your logic here inverted `if(IsValidUrl($("input[name='url']").val())`?

Comment: a typo, I forgot `!` symbol

Comment: `$("#test").on("submit", function(){` actually submitting form so why you added `$(this).submit();` ..? even i tried your code its working on first click for me in IE 7 And 8

Comment: @DipeshParmar: It is optionally, I just added to check if works. But is not working :)

Comment: what ver of jQuery do you use? why do you use `$("input[class='required']")` instead of `$("input.required")`? or even shorter: `$(".required").removeClass("error").each(function() { ... });`

Comment: @SnakeEyes what version you are trying on...?? its worked for me in IE 7 and 8

Comment: @DipeshParmar: I use 1.9.1 version

Comment: Probably won't solve your problem, but why are you setting a variable result, if you're already returning true/false? On every possible error, just return false. Otherwise, true.

Comment: @SnakeEyes as **MelanciaUK** said, you don't need `result`, try to return `true` when everything's ok

Comment: @MelanciaUK: post your answer as separate answer and I'll accept it :)

Comment: I was just point out an enhancement, not a solution. But I've posted as an answer anyway. Maybe it solves your issue. Who knows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two options here. On both you need to stop the submit event and validate the form.

- One is to go through all the fields in the form, add the class error to the invalid ones (if there's any), set the variable result and return (or submit if everything is alright).
- The other is to stop the test at the first invalid field found, not using the variable result, and return (or submit if everything is alright).

**JS**

```
$(function () {
    $("#test").on("submit", function (e) {
        // Stop the submit, because you need to validate the form before proceeding.
        e.preventDefault();

        // Check the comments below to decide for the use of the variable.
        var result = true;

        $(".required").removeClass("error");
        $.each($("input.required"), function (k, v) {
            // Test for empty fields or, if it's the URL, check whether is valid.
            if ($(this).val() === "" || ($(this).attr("name") == "url" && !IsValidUrl($(this).val())) {
                // Add class error to the invalid fields.
                $(this).addClass("error");

                // At this point, you could just return false stopping the loop,
                // or keep going to make sure all the invalid fields will get the
                // class error. In this case, you can still use the variable result.
                result = false;

                // Keep going, so, no return.
                // return false;
            }
        });

        // If you decided to carry on through all the fields, and don't return
        // false at the first error, test for the result value.
        // As this is the case...
        if (!result) return false;
        else $(this).submit();

        // If you didn't return previously...
        // $(this).submit();
    });
});
```